# Why is my matplotlib plot either off or incomplete when plotting a pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to relate a sample from a series with the series itself in a plot with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
# Create random walk data with a time series index
rnd_index = pd.date_range(start='2022-09-01', end='2022-09-30', freq='1D')
np.random.seed(0)
rnd_data = np.random.randint(-2, 4, size=(len(rnd_index))).cumsum()/10
series = pd.Series(rnd_data, index=rnd_index)
# Subsample fridays from the series
# Set up axis for plotting
ax = plt.gca()
series.plot(alpha=0.5, ax=ax)
sub_series = series.asfreq(freq="W-FRI")
sub_series.plot(alpha=0.5, style="+", ax=ax)
plt.legend(['series', 'sub_series'], loc='upper left')
```

This ends up in the following plot:

[image: off plot]
One can barely see it, but the first data point from the `sub_series` is cut in half on the left side. Looking at the data one can see that the first Friday on the 2nd of September is in both `series` and `sub_series` with a value of `0.5`.

**1) Why is the `sub_series` data offset from `series`?**

The second thing I don't understand here is when we reorder the plotting part in this way:

```
sub_series = series.copy(deep=True).asfreq(freq="W-FRI")
sub_series.plot(alpha=0.5, style="+", ax=ax)
series.plot(alpha=0.5, ax=ax)
```

We end up with this plot:
[image: missing data points]
Data is aligned now, but a lot of data is missing.

**2) Why is the `series` data subsampled in the plot?**

I guess this stems from a wrong understanding of the mechanism at work. To me it seems the pandas part is allright because the data output is like I would expect it (sub-sampled and correct values for the indicees). The behavior of matplotlib on the other hand I don't understand. Plotting `series` and `sub_series` individually gives the expected results. Combining them ends up in disaster (think about the wrong conclusions you would draw from misaligned indicees). Thank's for enligthning me. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an actual bug of pandas. If you check github, you'll find several (unsolved issues).
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11574
or here:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29719

The problem does not occur if you use matplotlib directly as a workaround:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 7))
ax.plot(series.index, series.values)
ax.scatter(sub_series.index, sub_series.values,marker='+',c  = 'orange')
ax.set_xlim (np.datetime64('2022-08-30'), np.datetime64('2022-10-01') )
plt.legend(['series', 'sub_series'], loc='upper left')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Phillip Steiner. It's really unfortunate when one runs into such bugs in the very beginning. The tip to use matplotlib directly is probably the best way anyway as pandas plot method is just a convenience wrapper.